# Eclipse warning error for unused function

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I get a "unused static function" warning in Eclipse for code that looks like this:

my.c:

```
static void myfunc(void) {  // This line gives unused warning.
   printf("in myfunc()");
}
typedef void(* myfunctyp)(void);

#include "my_generated.h"
```

my_generated.h:

```
myfunctyp mylist[] = {
   myfunc,
   0
}
```

my_generated.h is a generated code so I cannot just put the array in the .c file.

My Questions are:

1. How can I tell Eclipse to look into the include file so it can accurately determine that the function is used?
2. If I cannot get #1, how can I add an indicator in the source code to tell eclipse that this particular warning is okay?  I am aware that I can change Window->Preferences->Code Analysis -> Unused Static Function configuration to eliminate the error, but I would like something that "sticks" with the source.

[Edit (Addition)]: The function gets called in the main program like this:

```
mylist[0]();
```

If I move mylist[] declaration into the .c file, the warning error does not appear.

Comment: Are you actually *using* (calling) it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
#define MARKASUSED(x) if (0) { x(); }

static void myfunc(void) {
   printf("in myfunc()");
   MARKASUSED(myfunc)
}
```

The 'if (0)' should cause the compiler to remove the code with any kind of optimization on so it would not impact runtime at all.

I don't think this solution is ideal, but it meets my immediate needs.